# Get Random Time Between Midnight to Current Time

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to get the get the random time between **midnight** and the **current time** in seconds.

## Example

`12:01 AM -> 10:15 AM` of today which is 04/02/2016

```
def random_date(start, end):
    delta = end - start
    int_delta = (delta.days * 24 * 60 * 60) + delta.seconds
    random_second = randrange(int_delta)
    return start + timedelta(seconds=random_second)

start = datetime.datetime.strptime('2016-04-02 12:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
end = datetime.datetime.strptime(strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', gmtime()), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print random_date(start, end)
```

## Result

```
python new_visitor.py 
2016-04-02 04:49:54
──[/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/python] 
└── python new_visitor.py 
2016-04-02 09:06:15
──[/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/python] 
└── python new_visitor.py 
2016-04-02 08:59:22
──[/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/python] 
└── python new_visitor.py 
2016-04-02 **12:36:38**
──[/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/code/python] 
└── python new_visitor.py 
2016-04-02 02:38:54
```

Current time is 10:22 AM; I went passed the current time.

Comment: Could you add the `import` at the top for a newbie like me to understand where the functions come from?

Comment: Will do, sorry ab that.

Comment: Looking at the output, where exactly are you going past the range? Can you try and print the 12:36 part with am/pm sign?

Comment: What do you want to get if there is a DST transition and the result random time does not exist in the local time ("spring forward" transition)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the current time, subtract the current date at midnight to get a `timedelta` giving you the number of seconds, use `random.randrange()` to get a new offset and translate that back with the help of `timedelta` again:

```
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta
import random

now = datetime.now()
midnight = datetime.combine(now.date(), time.min)
delta = int((now - midnight).total_seconds())
random_dt = midnight + timedelta(seconds=random.randrange(delta))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta
>>> import random
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> midnight = datetime.combine(now.date(), time.min)
>>> delta = int((now - midnight).total_seconds())
>>> midnight + timedelta(seconds=random.randrange(delta))
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 2, 2, 11, 11)
>>> midnight + timedelta(seconds=random.randrange(delta))
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 2, 0, 45, 35)
>>> midnight + timedelta(seconds=random.randrange(delta))
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 2, 5, 56, 58)
>>> midnight + timedelta(seconds=random.randrange(delta))
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 2, 4, 35, 47)
>>> midnight + timedelta(seconds=random.randrange(delta))
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 2, 2, 10, 1)
```

Comment: So this is how you grab the midnight `midnight = datetime.combine(now.date(), time())` ?

Comment: @ihue: yes, `time()` with no arguments, or perhaps `time.MIN`, both give you midnight.

Comment: May I ask why you include `>>>` as part of your answer, is it meaning anything in python world ?

Comment: Need to be careful with `.total_seconds()` it can return a `float` which'll break `randrange` - using `delta.seconds` was fine as long as it's the midnight the same day as the max seconds will be in range...

Comment: @ihue: that's the output of the Python interactive interpreter; it is showing you the input I give it and the output it produces, so you can verify that my code works.

Comment: @JonClements: already addressed; note the `int()` call. You don't really need `timedelta.total_seconds()` for sub-day delta, but since the OP tried to do this with a start and end date I thought I'd toss that in anyway.

Comment: Ahh.. got it. Do you guys run your python code on the web or Terminal ? Do you know any good one I can use ?

Comment: @ihue: I run Python in the terminal.

Comment: Oh ok. Never mind. I came from a JSFiddle background, and I was think maybe there is something similar to that our there for Python.

Comment: Lastly, so if I want to maintain my format, I will just need to add the format to second parameter to your suggestion. Is it correct ?

Comment: @ihue: Just call the `strftime()` method on the resulting `datetime` instance:  `random_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: Will do. Thanks for answering my questions.

Comment: If there is a DST transition then your answer may produce non-existing local times (during "spring forward" transition) or it may bias the result against the ambiguous local time (during "fall back" transition).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modification of [@Martijn Pieters' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36374455/4279), to avoid producing bias or non-existing times around DST transitions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from random import randrange
from tzlocal import get_localzone  # $ pip install tzlocal

local_timezone = get_localzone()
now = datetime.now(local_timezone)
today = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day)
midnight = local_timezone.normalize(local_timezone.localize(today, is_dst=False))
max_seconds = int((now - midnight).total_seconds())
random_time = midnight + timedelta(seconds=randrange(max_seconds))
```

`is_dst=False` is used to avoid ambiguity if there is a DST transition at midnight.